# How to use metro css with codeigniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter, metro-ui-css

I am creating a reservation website with code igniter, but I am having a problem because I want to use metro css instead of bootstrap. how can I do that? thanks in advance. :) I want to know if using metro css is possible with code igniter. Please help me. I will really appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom Meto CSS library which you can download from here

[github.com](https://github.com/zulfinjuliant/codemetro)

---

**Introduction**

Code Metro (Codeigniter Metro UI CSS) kick starts the development process of the web development process by including Metro UI CSS into CodeIgniter. With this custom Codeigniter framework, you can make a site with an metro UI interface. It also includes certain libraries such as AWS and Facebook in-case you are developing applications requiring those SDKs. Now start working on your idea.

> ***Note*: There are lot configurations  to be done. So to through link carefully.**

Comment: Note that is CI 2.1.4 version.

Comment: @christiaaan happy to help